# jasmine test a Restangular response

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, restangular

I'm calling

```
Restangular.all('resource').getList()
```

and I want to test that the results are as expected.

In my test, I want to make this work

```
expectedResp = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 };
expect(resp).toEqual(expectedResp);
```

The problem is that the resp from restangular is restangularized, meaning it contains a bunch of members in addition to the data returned from the rest call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
expectedResp = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 };
expect(resp).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(expectedResp));
```